# InstallScripts vs db_schema for new EAV attribute

Tags: magento2, database, eav

I'm in the process of adding new fields to my registration page. I know that we're now supposed to use db_schema instead of InstallScripts, but how can I make sure that they're seen as customer attributes, and editable with he rest of customer information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db_schema.xml used only for table fields. It means that you can add only table field by db_schema, but not Magento EAV attribute.

To add new customer attribute you can use the following guide https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-product-attribute-programmatically.html

But in attribute creating `InstallData::install` method you should add `'used_in_forms'` property to attribute with content: `'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']`
And if you are using Magento Enterprise edition, this attribute will be automatically shown on frontend otherwise you should display it manually.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen the existing tutorials, but I've seen that $this->attributeResource->save() was being depricated. Is there an updated way to do it?

Comment: Also, how would you add multiple values? Throw the whole thing into a foreach?

Comment: 1. I think that using deprecated things in Install/Upgrades scrips is not a big deal.
2. Yep, to add several attributes you should move attributes codes to array, and do it via foreach loop.